What's the derivative of the Kronecker product of a matrix and itself?
Let $X\in{\mathbb{R}}^{m{\times}n}$ be a general matrix,
what's the derivative of $X{\otimes}X$?
i.e. I want to calculate
$\frac{{\mathrm{d}}(X{\otimes}X)}{{\mathrm{d}}X}$,
or the derivative of its vertorization:
$\frac{{\mathrm{d}}\left[vec(X{\otimes}X)\right]}{{\mathrm{d}}\left[vec(X)\right]}$.

Interesting things there

Apply Leibniz rule, i.e.
$$
\mathrm{d}(X \otimes X) = \mathrm{d}X \otimes X + X \otimes \mathrm{d}X
$$

Thanks for your answer!
